# How to match a string, ignoring ending newline?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to be able to match an entire string (hence the word boundaries) against a pattern "ABC" ("ABC" is just used for convenience, I don't want to check for equality with a fixed string), so newlines are significant to me. However it appears that a single "\n" when put at the end of a string is ignored. Is there something wrong with my pattern?

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^ABC$");
string[] strings =
{
    "ABC",//True
    "ABC\n",//True: But, I want it to say false.
    "ABC\n\n",//False
    "\nABC",//False
    "ABC\r",//False
    "ABC\r\n",//False
    "ABC\n\r"//False
};
foreach(string s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(s));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\AABC\z");
```

`\A` = Anchor for beginning of string
`\z` = Anchor for end of string
`^` = Anchor for beginning of line
`$` = Anchor for end of line

Comment: Thanks. Found this after your answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=VS.100).aspx